# How do I catch a click() failure?

Tags: python, selenium

Is there a way for selenium to determine whether a `click()` function executed properly?

Let's say a webpage has a form with a submit button. I am using selenium to click on the submit button. How would I determine if the `click()` occurred correctly? Right now I have code that looks like this:

```
try:
  button = driver.find_element_by_id('submit_button_id')
  button.click()
except NoSuchElementException:
  print('No such button found.')

# determine if the `click()` function actually worked.
try:
  driver.find_element_by_id(
    'new_id_that_only_occurs_after_button_click'
  )
except NoSuchElementException:
  # code to retry button click
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing better than checking that on click page changes in the way you are expecting. So what you are doing is right. The only improvement I would do is change "find" to "wait", something like [in the example shown here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html#explicit-waits):

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    .until(
       EC.presence_of_element_located(
           (By.ID,
            'new_id_that_only_occurs_after_button_click'))
```

That way the test is more reliable (if response to click action takes a bit of time, the test will not fail).